# Downloading files in iOS pwa

Tags: ios, download, progressive-web-apps

I am currently working on an progressive web app. The issue I experience is downloading a file is not working on iOS. This only happens when I use standalone or fullscreen modus. minimal-ui works fine and just the safari browser also works fine. Is this an Apple issue, due to their limited support of a PWA? If so can i do anything to make it work?

Comment: Kindly check this [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/95911) about this issue. You can try to use `window.open()` or `iframe` with `src` -> `src='https://docs.google.com/gview?url=urltoyour.pdf&embedded=true'`.